# Kill a python process

Tags: python, macos

I wrote a python script but accidentally put an infinite while loop in my script.

How do I kill the process? I've tried `ctrl+c` but with no success.

Are there any other option to try?

I'm on Mac Os X 10.7.2 with python 2.7

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`ps a` to get the PID of your process. `kill -9 <pid>` to send it the unblockable SIGKILL signal.

Note that I only have a Linux box in front of me to test, so the OS X commands may be slightly different.

Comment: worked perfectly thanks. Out of curiosity what is the -9 flag for?

Comment: `SIGKILL` is signal number 9. `kill -X` is shorthand for `kill -s SIGNAME` if you don't want to type the symbolic name, and you know the number. I believe if you do `kill -l` (that's a lowercase L) it will list the signals and numbers on your system.

Answer (score 33):

Try `Ctrl+\` to send a SIGQUIT.

Answer (score 25):

try this.

```
pkill -9 python

or

ps -ef|grep python
kill -9 <pid>

or

lsof -i :port

or 
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Open Activity monitor, go to the Processes tab, and highlight python.exe and quit it by clicking Quit.

Comment: this is maybe not the answer everyone likes, but it's still correct. You can use the activity monitor to kill it.