# Knowing which python process to kill on linux?

Tags: python, linux

I've run a python script on the command line that can't be killed with ctrl-C (SIGINT).

```
 $ ./bad_script.py
 ^CTraceback(most recent call last):
 ...
 KeboardInterrupt
 ^C
 ^C
 ...
 <I give up>
```

When I look for this python process on another command line I see many options:

```
 $ pidof python
 1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666   # Which one is bad_script.py?
```

I want to kill my bad_script.py process, not the innocents.

Note this is not a duplicate of other questions that are similar because I want to know *which* process to kill:

- [OSX Terminal: How to kill all processes with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334761/osx-teminal-how-to-kill-all-processes-with-the-same-name)
- [Kill a python process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066221/kill-a-python-process)
- [Kill python process with pkill python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631451/kill-python-process-with-pkill-python)

Comment: `pps aux | grep bad_script | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: Normally I do `ctrl-z` and then use `kill -9 %1` to kill the process in bash via its job number.

Comment: Press `C-Z` to stop it, then use your shell's kill: `kill %`. This way, you won't miss.

Comment: Did you run the script from a different tty (window) than the other scripts? You can (sometimes) examine the the (pseudo)tty to find and identify the correct process (pid) (unless you started most/all processes from the same terminal/tty/window).

Comment: The age of the process can be an indication of which process (unless you started them all at the same time.

Comment: Can you identify from the command line arguments? You might be able to use the /proc virtual filesystem to examine the command line arguments, ex: cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline

Comment: Or you could send SIGSTOP to each process until you find the one you want to stop, and selectively restart the ones you want to keep by sending SIGCONT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of options. For example you can run the following `ps` command to list all running programs and use `grep`:

```
ps aux | grep bad_script
```

or if you have access to the source code, you could print the process id inside the script, at the start of the program:

```
import os
print os.getpid()
```

or just press `Ctrl-\` to kill it in a different way by sending the `SIGQUIT` signal.